# How to separate/decouple instance creation of children when creating core model in DDD

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design

A course can have multiple activities, i.e. Training, Exam, Project, Book, Article, and Task.
Following are the requirements:

- Allow the teacher to schedule a course.
- Allow the teacher to schedule different activities in the said course.
- Display list of activities to the student for a selected course, in a specified date range.

The above requirements lead me to create two aggregates.

- CourseAggregate
- ActivityAggregate

Why?
A course can be created without any activities, but only in draft state. A course can be scheduled on for a different set of students. 
An activity can be created independent of course, and later on, linked to a course. 
Activities can be fetched with a date range only for a given student.

```
protected abstract class Activity
{
    public Guid Id {get; private set;}
}
protected class Training : Activity
{
..... Addiontal properties 
}
protected class Exam : Activity
{
....Addiontal properties and behavior.
    public bool AllowGrading => true;
}
.... Other childern of activity..hence more classes.
```

Questions:

- Is it the right approach to go with inheritance?
- Since I marked the constructor protected, so the client code will not use the new operator, and will not have direct knowledge of children. I am struggling to figure out how the client should create an instance of the activity. For example:

```
[Test]
public void ActivityFactoryShouldCreateCorrectActivityType(){
   var activity= ActivityFactory.CreateActivity(activityType:"Training", title:"Training", DueDate: "date".......)

}
```

Problem is, each subtype might want to enforce different invariants for the entity to be correctly created. For example, Exam activity requires information about the scale of grading.

How to solve correctly implement it or which pattern suits better here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one of the problem that frquently pops up when using a language like C# or Java. That is an implementational problem more than it is modeling issue.

The thing is that you do have these concepts: `Exam`, `Training` etc. that are concrete. On the other hand you can derive a common concept for them: `Activity`.

Here are couple of questions that we need to ask before we consider an implementation.

- What it needs to do with these concepts?
- How does it works with them?
- How many parts of the system are interested in the concrete concepts `Exam`, `Training` etc. and how many of it is interested in the common concept of `Activity`?
- Do you expect to add many more concepts that will be `Activities`? This will affect how you evolve your system.

Let's say that your system doesn't use the concept of `Activity` much and it wont have many more activities added. In this case we can just ignore `Activity` and just use concrete concepts. This say there is no problem in creating them.

Let's say that your system will use the concept of `Activity` and you need to add more types of activities.

This doesn't undermine the fact that your system will know of the different concrete types of activities. It will create them, work with them etc. Even when your system is working with the concept of activity it will probably still need to know the concrete type of the activity so it can do something with it.

This kind of logic shows a problem with the way that we think when we use an OOP language like C# of Java. We are trained as developers. usually people say that casting is bad. You sould somehow define a base class or an interface and let subclasses of interface implementers define a behavior and the other parts of the system shouldn't know the concrete type.

And this it true for some parts of the system and for come concepts. Take for example a `Serializer`. You can define an interface `ISerializer` with a method `Serialize`. The system that uses a serializer may use the interface without having to know the concrete type as each class that implements the `ISerializer` interface will add a *different implementation* of the same `interface`.

Not every problem is like that. Sometimes your system needs to know what it deals with. This is where i thing we can learn something from languages like JavaScript. There what you have is an object that is non specific and use can just attach properties to it. The object is what it's properties define it to be.

The concept of [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is interesting: *"If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck"*

If you system needs to work with `Exam` it should work with it not with an `Activity`. If it has an `Activity` it *should* be able to figure out it it's indeed an `Exam` because this is that it needs.

Now we live in the strong typed world and it has it's good parts. I love strong typing and what it gives you, but also some problems are more difficult to deal with.

You can use classes with inheritance to implement this. You also use interfaces instead of having classes to capture different concepts. Yet your system will need to do some casting to determine the concrete type of what is working with. We can make it's life a bit easier if we capture the fact that we have different types of `Activities` explicitly

Here's an example:

```
public enum ActivityType { Exam, Trainig, Project, Task }

public class Activity {

    public Guid ID { get; private set; }
    public abstract ActivityType Type { get; }
    // other stuff
}

public class Exam : Activity {

    public override ActivityType Type {
        get { return ActivityType.Exam; }
    }
    // other stuff
}

public class SomeClass {

    public void SomeAction(Activity activity) {

        if(activity.Type == ActivityType.Exam) {
            var examActivity = (Exam)activity;
            // do something with examActivity
        }
    }
}
```

If creating your activities have some logic related to them you can use a `Factory` to create them by using their concrete types.

```
public class ExamFactory {

    public Exam CreateSummerExam(string name, //other stuff) {
        // Enfore constraints
        return new Exam(new Guid(), name,....);
    }
}
```

Or add a `Factory` to the concrete type:

```
public class Exam : Activity {

    public static Exam CreateSummerExam() { 
       // Enfore constraints
        return new Exam();
    }

    private Exam() { }
}
```

Or just use a public constructor if creating these objects is not complex.

If you realy want to hide the classes to allow yourself some freedom of implementation then use interfaces:

```
// **Domain.dll**

public enum ActivityType { Exam, Training }

public interface IActivity {

    ActivityType Type { get; }
}

public interface IExam : IActivity { }

internal class Exam : IExam { }

public class ActivityFactory {

    public IExam CreateExam() { return new Exam(); }
    public ITraining CreateTraining() { return new Training(); }
    // other concrete activities
}
```

This way you don't allow clien code to have access to classes. You can give them access to public interfaces and keep other implementation specific methods internal to your Domain.dll. Clients of these concepts can still use casting to use the appropriate type that they need, but this time they will use interfaces.

Here's a good [article](https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/roles.pdf) on this. In it Martin Fowler says:

> With OO programs you try to avoid asking an object whether it is an
>   instance of a type. But sometimes that is legitamate information for a
>   client to use, perhaps for a GUI display. Remember that asking an
>   object if it is an instance of a type is something different than
>   asking it if it is an instance of a class, since the types
>   (interfaces) and the classes (implementations) can be different.

EDIT:

Another implementation of this is to treat an `Activity` as a container that you can attach different things to it. This will give you a more flexible system. Unfortunately this won't remove the need for switching and checking if various features are present in your entity. It's possible to some degree but depending on your concrete case you may need to process an `Activity` from some external component and will need to swith and check.

For example you may want to generate some report. You may need to get some activities, process them and then generate some report based on some data stored in them. This cannot happen with attaching components to one activity as this operation requires multiple activities not a single one.

There are a lot of systems that do this kind of thing. Here are some examples:

- Computer Games use something that is called [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system).These systems are data oriented where an `Entity` is comprised of different `Components`. Each system then checks to see if a `Component` is attached to an `Entity`. For example you have a `Rendering system` that renders your scene with all players and stuff. This system will check if an entity has attached `3D model component`. If it has it will render it.
- The same approach is used in [Flow Based Programming](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/index.shtml). It is also data driven where you send Information Packets that are composed of different properties. These properties can be simple or complex. Then you have `Processes` that are connected and pass data between each other. Each `Process` will search for specific type of data in a IP to check if it's supported by it.
- [Unity](https://unity.com/) also supports using Entity Component System. But it also supports another similar approach to having active components that contain behavior and logic instead of passive data that is processed from external systems.
- [Feature based programming](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/dsb/SPLC/Nominations/Prehofer01.pdf). Uses the notion of features that you can add to an object. It's used in CAD/CAM system, banking systems and many more

It's a good approach to use when having dynamic data that needs to be processed. Unfortunately this won't remove the need to do some `if/else` and `swich`. As already mentioned, when you need to process collections of `Activities` you will need to do some checking.

Note that the systems above don't try to avoid this. On the contrary. They embrace this fact and use dynamic data. It's no different then having a type fo the activities and `switching` on it. It's just that their approach give a more flexible system at the expence of doing a lot of checks.

If you system doesn't require that kind of dynamic data you can just use concrete classes instead of data objects that can store unlimited number of things. This will simplify some parts of your application. If you do need to compose different objects then you can use one of the approaches above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for taking the time to answer the question in detail & with beautiful insights.
Consider we are developing https://coursera.org site. There are two major high-level goals which system has to achieve.
- Teacher/Course Creator should be able to create (schedule) a Course. From creator point of view, he/she want to add Exam, training or other activities to course. But he/she will refer to it as "I am scheduling an exam activity in this course for the following dates, with the following criteria of fail/pass" or "I am scheduling a training activity, in this course." Now, if we go with IActivity interface approach along with ActvityType Enum, all the client code, will be using switch or if/else to see what type of activity it is, and this will flow to top-level i.e. UI, or even controllers or consumer classes,

```
if(activity.type==exam){ ((Exam)IActivity).DoSomething();}
```

But this looks acceptable given there is no good alternative, but it really clutters your code.
- From a student perspective, he/she is only interested in the following
-- show me the list of all activities I have to perform, but tell me what type of activities they are
-- Once I attempt/do an activity, he/she expect different behavior as well, for example, Training does not have any grading attached to it, while exam does.
--- Exam is allowed to take only once.
--- Summary Exam grading is different than Full Exam.
--- Summary Exam Allow Late Submission while Exam does not have that feature at all.

Now again in order to call the correct behavior of IActivity, enum is helpful but it is cluttering the code base at all levels, where the decision has to be made. And IActivity does not know about the behavior Exam at all, and exam can be of multiple types, thus adding to the complexity so another enum to see what kind of exam it is since Summary Exam and Full Exam only differs in grading behavior, and everything else is same. Now with this, another switch statement or if/else on all consumer classes.
* Factories will help with this, but I am worried it will become too complex, having different methods in factories, since Exam can be in a valid state (draft) with a different combination of properties. 
So the system is interested both in Activity and concrete types i.e. Exam, Training, etc but in different scope.

** Additional complexity, what if the teacher wants to create a new type of activity which is saying "Its Path activity, the exam is only available when the student takes this training." Now, the student is still interested to see a list of all activities, just want to know the type of it (as a label).

Lately, I have been thinking about composition instead of inheritance, where there is only one type, Activity, and it has a set of a feature collection. Each feature contains its own behavior in its own class. Have not done it before, not sure if this sort of approach exists or even beneficial.

Thanks again for the detailed answer again, would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: That's actually a good approach. I'll add an edit to my answer wtih more information on it with links to explore more options. I don't think that you can completely avoid the need to `swith` or do `if/else` when you are dealing with dynamic data in a complex system. Check out the resources on my answer for more information on the issue. It's possible to minize it, but to remove it completely is possible but will depend on your system.

Comment: Since you're a new member of stack overflow, here are some things to consider. If you do find an answer useful you should either accept it or vote for it. Don't add answers to your own questions. If you need to ask something, write comments to answers, so the person who wrote the answer can add additional information of remove something.

Comment: Thanks, acknowledged. Appreciate the help.